# User Input Check Before Insert to Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-injection

I have a form in my MVC 5 Webb App, a very simple form for "contact us":

-Name

-Email

-Subject

-Message (body)

I have to check the strings that the user input.

How can I check it in .NET ?

---

Update:

As Darin suggested, a Parameterizing Queries will take care of that, but I have a problem with implementation it with my architecture design of my web application:

**I have a Ado Helper Class:**

```
public class AdoHelper
{
    static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL_DB"].ConnectionString;


    public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string query)
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            SqlDataAdapter tableAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            tableAdapter.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }

    public static void ExecuteNonQuery(string query)
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    public static object ExecuteScalar(string query)
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            return command.ExecuteScalar();
        }

    }

}
```

**And I have Data Queries Class:** ( I display here only the relevant function to this question)

```
     public class DataQueries
    {
        public static void InsertContactForm(ContactForm form)
        {
            try
            {
                string query = "INSERT INTO ContactForm (Name, Email, Subject, Message, Reply) VALUES ( '" + form.Name + "','" + form.Email + "','" + form.Subject + "','" + form.Message + "','" + form.Reply + "')";

                AdoHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(query);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
}
```

When I want to insert data to my DB I call to a Data Queries function that communicate with the Ado Helper Class.

So the query pass to Ado Helper function as string well formed and ready to go, this creates a problem because I cant use parameters in the Ado Helper class (where I have SQL command instance).

Are there any workaround to this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to check against SQL injection? All you have to do is to make sure that you are properly encoding the user input on the page when reading it back from the database. Also make sure you are using parametrized queries when storing those values and you should be safe.

Comment: You right, how can I check for all kind of characters that I can get from the user that wont interrupt the insert ? like ' and etc..

Comment: You don't need to be checking for anything like that. You should be simply using parametrized queries when storing them in your SQL and when rendering them back simply HTML encode the values. By the way if you are using an ORM it probably already takes care for issuing parametrized queries to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: The reason I asked is I test my form submit and enter a name with a "'" char and some more weird character, I got SQL exception.
So "parametrized queries" will fix that ?

Comment: Yes, of course that parametrized queries will fix that. That;s exactly what they are designed for.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov see my edit maybe youll had an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `AdoHelper` class is currently vulnerable to SQL injection. In order to avoid that you need to use parametrized queries. So I would start by refactoring this AdoHelper class so that it suits better those needs:

```
public class AdoHelper
{
    private static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL_DB"].ConnectionString;

    public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string query, IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var command = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            con.Open();
            command.CommandText = query;
            foreach (var p in parameters)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.Key, p.Value);
            }

            return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

and then you could call this method in order to perform the `INSERT` statement:

```
AdoHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(
    "INSERT INTO ContactForm (Name, Email, Subject, Message, Reply) VALUES (@Name, @Email, @Subject, @Message, @Reply)",
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "@Name", "form.Name" },
        { "@Email", "form.Email" },
        { "@Subject", "form.Subject" },
        { "@Message", "form.Message" },
        { "@Reply", "form.Reply" }
    }
);
```

Comment: Now I need to rewrite it :) Thanks Darin

Answer (score 1):

What you need is parametrized queries. In the `cmd` object in ADO.NET, for example, there is a straight forward to do that:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    // Add the input parameter and set its properties.
    using (var parameter = new SqlParameter())
    {
        parameter.ParameterName = "@CategoryName";
        parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameter.Value = categoryName;
        // Add the parameter to the Parameters collection. 
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        // Now you can execute query
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I have other problem with this approach, see my edit of the original message.

Comment: Check the link, you can parametrize SQL strings like: `INSERT INTO ContactForm (Name) VALUES (@Name)`. `@Name` needs to match `ParameterName`.